# Is there a command which displays options like `errexit` and `braceexpand` other than `help set`?

Tags: bash, options, env, shopt

If you type `help set`, then - among other things - a list of shell options is displayed. But these options are not the same as those displayed with `shopt`. And different also from those displayed with `set` and `env`.

Is there a command which displays options such as `errexit` and `braceexpand` and their current values?

Also, what is the connection between the different option commands? What does `set` display that `env` doesn't / what does `shopt` display that `set` doesn't / etc ?

(bash 3.2.51 on Mac OS X 10.9.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `set -o`:

```
$ set -o
allexport       off
braceexpand     on
emacs           on
errexit         off
errtrace        off
functrace       off
hashall         on
histexpand      on
history         on
ignoreeof       off
interactive-comments    on
keyword         off
monitor         on
noclobber       off
noexec          off
noglob          off
nolog           off
notify          off
nounset         off
onecmd          off
physical        off
pipefail        off
posix           off
privileged      off
verbose         off
vi              off
xtrace          off
```

Also see [Set and Shopt - Why Two?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32409/set-and-shopt-why-two)